# Array seems empty with Implode on array_values

Tags: php, foreach, implode

Some assistance would be greatly appreciated:

The 'foreach' section works perfectly and echo's the result set perfectly; as soon as I try the implode it fails? Thank you!

```
$ctr = 0;
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $RespondentsResultSetArray[$ctr] = array(
        "Firstname" => $row['cnt_firstname'],
        "Lastname" => $row['cnt_lastname']
    );

    $ctr = $ctr + 1;
}

foreach ($RespondentsResultSetArray as $key) {
    echo $key["Firstname"] . ' ' . $key["Lastname"] . ', ';
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);

echo implode(', ',array_values($RespondentsResultSetArray));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing an array of arrays to `implode` function. Here is a little deviation of your code, that should get you to the same result:

```
$full_array = array();
foreach ($RespondentsResultSetArray as $key) {
    echo $key["Firstname"] . ' ' . $key["Lastname"] . ', ';
    array_push($full_array,$key["Firstname"]);
    array_push($full_array,$key["Lastname"]);

}



echo implode(', ',$full_array);
```

Also, for the future, try to chose smaller names for your variables, and use lowercase for your variable names and array index.

Comment: Thank you for advice and answer, this has solved my problem! I just made some slight modifications for the output to look the same as the foreach.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
implode(',',$RespondentsResultSetArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

The php implode function accepts an array of strings.
You are not passing it an array of strings.

To user1844933 that just answered, your suggestion would pass implode an array of arrays. That won't work for the same reason.

```
$RespondentsResultSetArray=array();
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    array_push($RespondentsResultSetArray,$row['cnt_firstname'].' '.$row['cnt_lastname']);
}
$saved_to_variable=implode(', '$RespondentsResultSetArray);
```

Will create an array of strings which you can then implode

Since you recently commented that you want to save it to a variable rather than echo it, I just changed the last line of the example code.  I believe that will give you the properly spaced, and delimited string that you desire.

Comment: Thank you, any possible assistance on passing it what it needs, or should I use a method other than implode similar to foreach, as my end goal is to have one string correctly spaced with commas added saved to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

since`$RespondentsResultSetArray` is multidimensional array use `foreach` loop before echo

```
$string = ""; 
foreach($RespondentsResultSetArray as $values)
{
echo implode(array_values($values),",");
$string= $string.",".implode(array_values($values),",");
}

$string=ltrim($string,",");
echo $string;
```

[Demo](http://3v4l.org/c6APn)